# Cut and then paste at the beginning of the line

Tags: cut-copy-paste

An example:

```
Doe, John
```

And I want:

```
John Doe
```

I cut `Doe` with <kbd>D</kbd>, and then <kbd>0</kbd> and then <kbd>p</kbd>

But what I get is this:

```
DJohn oe,
```

How to do this right?

Comment: I do not fully understand your example. you cuttet John not Doe did you ?
Your pasting problems seems to be a matter of using p instead you should use P to paste before.

Comment: That is it. And I made a mistake. The cut should have been John of course. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Lowercase 'p' will paste AFTER the cursor. Use a capital 'P' and it will end up BEFORE the cursor. It will not, however, insert a space, so you will end up with  "JohnDoe,".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on the "D", you may also <kbd>dtJA</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, which will leave you with `John Doe,` with the cursor at the end, to delete the rest.

An alternative would also be `s/\v(\w+), (\w+)/\2 \1/`